# Yii:user - file Profile Field

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I've added a file type Profile Field in Yii:user. The file selection was added to the profile edit form, but when I select an image I get an error "Image cannot be blank".

I've set the ajax validation to false and now I get this error after submit.

What should I do?

Comment: can you show some code ?

Comment: I haven't added any code. I've installed the yii-user extension and added a file field through the Profile Field manager

Answer (score 3):

You need to edit your **profile** field and set other **validator** value to something like this:

```
 {"file":{"allowEmpty":"true","maxFiles":"1","types":"jpg, jpeg, gif, png"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two important things you need to do: add a new validation rule to the Profile Field model that looks something like this:

```
array('image', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png'),
```

And change the form tag to include 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data' (I normally add that using the htmlOptions array in CActiveForm / CForm).

Here is a wiki page talking about how to upload files using a model, in case you haven't seen it yet: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/

Comment: I made sure there is a validation rule and the form is set as 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data' but I still get this error. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this field for a profile photo? If it is, you could use this widget designed for yii-user: https://github.com/rizkyramadhan/yii-user-profilepic